# AF Networking 3.x Singleton IOS design error

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, afnetworking

Hi i'm creating a AFNetworking 3.0 Singleton to use throughout the app.

Here is my singleton

my `ApiClient.h`

```
@interface ApiClient : AFHTTPSessionManager
+ (ApiClient *)sharedInstance;
```

my `ApiClient.m`

```
+ (ApiClient *)sharedInstance {
    static ApiClient *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:SINGPOST_BASE_URL] sessionConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];
    });

    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    if ((self = [super initWithBaseURL:url])) {
        AFJSONRequestSerializer *serializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
        [serializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [serializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
    }

    return self;
}
```

There is something wrong with my design. Every time when i call the `[Api Client] shareIntance` i need to include

```
[ApiClient sharedInstance].responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [[ApiClient sharedInstance].responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
```

for example

```
- (void)getSingpostContentsOnSuccess:(ApiClientSuccess)success onFailure:(ApiClientFailure)failure {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"singpost-contents.php"
                                                                              relativeToURL:[NSURL URLWithString:CMS_BASE_URL]]];

    [ApiClient sharedInstance].responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [[ApiClient sharedInstance].responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];


    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [ApiClient.sharedInstance dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            failure(error);
            //            [self reportAPIIssueURL:[request.URL absoluteString] payload:nil message:[error description]];
        } else {
            NSDictionary *jsonDict  = (NSDictionary *) responseObject;
            success(jsonDict);
        }
    }];
    [dataTask resume];
}
```

if not there will be error of unacceptable content-type. is there redundant? can I move the

```
[ApiClient sharedInstance].responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [[ApiClient sharedInstance].responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
```

to initiation of the shareIntance

And I try to reduce above code with

```
[[ApiClient sharedInstance].responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];
```

Which is not working also

Any help or suggestion is much appreciate! thanks!

Comment: In the `initWithBaseURL:`, you didn't set the Request Serializer to the sharedInstance. You could also put there the Response Serializer.

Comment: thanks a lot, how to properly init the singleton "sharedInstance"? and do you know why this code is not working [ApiClient sharedInstance].responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [[ApiClient sharedInstance].responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];

Comment: Could it be because `[ApiClient sharedInstance].responseSerializer` is `nil`?. Else in the `initWithBaseURL:` do self.requestSerializer = serializer;`

Comment: I still get the error Request failed: unacceptable content-type after add self.requestSerializer = serializer can only work with this code ApiClient sharedInstance].responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [[ApiClient sharedInstance].responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];

Comment: You are mixing response and request serializer. And in the `initWithBaseURL:` you have to create also the `responseSerializer`, and affect it to self.

Comment: Hi I have add AFHTTPResponseSerializer *responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer new];
        self.responseSerializer = responseSerializer;
not working and this one is not working also AFJSONResponseSerializer *responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
        self.responseSerializer = responseSerializer;

Comment: what is proper way to initiate the singleton of AFHTTPSessionManager?